# Jquery: get stars that have index less than the current clicked star

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with stars:

[image]

```
<aside class="rate review-rate">
                <span class="review-star" index="1">☆</span>
                <span class="review-star" index="2">☆</span>
                <span class="review-star" index="3">☆</span>
                <span class="review-star" index="4">☆</span>
                <span class="review-star" index="5">☆</span>
            </aside>
```

and a script that makes the star full when it's clicked:

```
$('.review-star').on('click', function () {
   /* desc = $(this).attr('data-desc'); //get the description
    $('#content').text(desc);*/
    alert("yes");
    alert($(this).attr("index"));
    $(this).text("★")

    var stars = $(".review-star").filter((index, el) => {
        return parseInt($(el).attr("index")) > $(this).attr("index");
    });
    console.log(stars);
    console.log(stars.length)
    for (var starsKey in stars) {
        //$(starsKey).text("★");
    //    console.log(starsKey);
    }
});
```

However I need to make the previous stars full as well. I tried getting all the stars with attribute `index` value less than that of the `$(this).attr("index")` but it didn't work.

**EDIT**:
The answers with `prevAll` are awesome, but if someone could point me as to what I was doing wrong in my code, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: In jQuery's `filter`, `this` is the same as `el`. Capture the value of the index attribute of `this` before running the `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you can simply use the `prevAll()` method. `addBack()` can also be used to include the element which was clicked. Try this:

```js
$('.review-star').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prevAll().addBack().text("★");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="rate review-rate">
  <span class="review-star" index="1">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="2">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="3">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="4">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="5">☆</span>
</aside>
```

Comment: Wow! I also managed to get it to make rating lower like this: `$(this).nextAll().addBack().text("☆");` `$(this).prevAll().addBack().text("★");` Thanks so much, it's pure magic!

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `prevAll()` and `nextAll()`

```js
$('.review-star').on('click', function () {
   /* desc = $(this).attr('data-desc'); //get the description
    $('#content').text(desc);*/
    //alert("yes");
    //alert($(this).attr("index"));
    $(this).text("★")

    //var stars = $(".review-star").filter((index, el) => {
    //    return parseInt($(el).attr("index")) > $(this).attr("index");
    //});
    //console.log(stars);
    //console.log(stars.length)
    
    $(this).prevAll().text("★");
    $(this).nextAll().text("☆");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="rate review-rate">
  <span class="review-star" index="1">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="2">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="3">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="4">☆</span>
  <span class="review-star" index="5">☆</span>
</aside>
```